# Product Images don't show (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce

My Product images appear, but when I click to enter the product page, the images are hidden and they appear only when I click. Some products show on other browsers. Some products  Show only on microsoft Edge.

**Edit:**
The real problem to that was cloudflare rocket loader, blocking some javascript of the website. By disabling that option it fixed the problem.
[image]

Comment: Note that this happens on products with children, i.e. variable products, and not on simple products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Css [woocommerce.css](https://www.tsigaradiko.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css?ver=2.5.5) has `.product.has-default-attributes.has-children > .images` class set `opacity` to `0` Change or remove this class Or override class from your themes css

```
.product.has-default-attributes.has-children > .images{opacity: 0;}
```

TO

```
.product.has-default-attributes.has-children > .images{opacity:1;}
```

Image is appear only on click Because after click `.image` class add the `opacity` to `1` using some `JQuery`

Comment: do you know why opacity is 0? Seems very bizarre to me, unless there's some JS to reveal them (which is broken on mine) but then they shouldn't be relying on JS to show images anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is CSS issue, in woocommerce.css this class `.product.has-default-attributes.has-children > .images` has `opacity:0` you need to set this class `opacity:1` bellow is the snippet

```
.product.has-default-attributes.has-children > .images {opacity :0}
```

Changes this line to

```
.product.has-default-attributes.has-children > .images{opacity :1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this css

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery {opacity: 1 !important;}
```

I don't really know the best way to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found this css on another support site and it fixed it for me:

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images.woocommerce-product-gallery 
{
opacity:100!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the following jquery code

```
$('.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images').css('opacity', 1);
```