# Featured Image doesn't show on the Product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, wordpress-featured-image

I'm struggling with my wordpress page, with woocommerce. The featured image should be showing as the first image on the product page, but isn't. I've read a few other threads, like this one:

[Product Images don't show (Woocommerce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717523/product-images-dont-show-woocommerce#37717644)
where they have some solutions, but the CSS they are proposing isn't working.

My page is here: [www.byjgk.com](http://www.byjgk.com) , and for example, if you check out a product category page, like: https://www.byjgk.com/product-category/dresses/ , and then select a dress (e.g.: https://www.byjgk.com/product/the-jersey-maxi-dress-petite-in-sandstone/), you ***should*** then see the same featured which was on the category page also appear as the first image on the product page as WELL/(in addition to the other 3 images that are there).

Normally, that's how the image feature works, so there must be some opacity/other problem.

I also did try changing the woocommerce.css file, (which was also a suggestion in the link above, to put this there:

.product.has-default-attributes.has-children > .images{opacity :1;}

but i didn't see any class called exactly that with the word "children".

I also tried to put the "jquery" that was suggested:

$('.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images').css('opacity', 1);

into the functions.php section, but it said this query had some sort of error, or it didn't like the "$" maybe...

Soooo, I'm at a loss. please help. I see a few people have asked about this on some other forums, but many don't figure it out.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some trial and error it seems like one of my own plugins was causing this conflict. If anyone is using this plugin, be aware of the potential - i haven't yet played with the settings on this pluging to see if that's changable.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-slider-for-woocommerce/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to update the theme, plugins and wordpress as well because something is not working properly for you, if the problem continues, start deactivating the plugins to understand what is causing this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to identify the plugin first, which is causing the problem?